# Fix for null Navigation Controller when pushing view in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have built my table using Storyboards. I have a Table View embedded in a Navigation Controller. My Details View is also a Table View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
    NHCDependantDetailsViewController *detailView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddDependant"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
  }
```

I've discovered that the problem is that my Navigation Controller is null. Unfortunately, I have no idea how or where to correctly fix this. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** I have followed the advice below to set the navigation controller as the initial view controller, but now I cannot reach my TableView. Perhaps the problem is evident in this image of my storyboard? Having two nav arrows there can't be good...

[image]

Comment: Just realize that you have 2 arrow to the shown Navigator Controller. The first top arrow should be connected to the Navigator Controller of the "Dependants View Contoller" thus the Dependant Table View is not skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your storyboard has 1 Table View which is embedded in a Navigation Controller and NHCDependantDetailsViewController which is also embedded in a Navigation Controller.

First of all, you need to set the the Navigation Controller of your table view as the initial view controller by ticking "Is Initial View Controller" on the attribute inspector.

Secondly, I think it is not necessary to embed NHCDependantDetailsViewController in a Navigation Controller as you can push many view controller to your main navigator controller.

Comment: Setting the navigation controller as 'Initial View Controller' seems to make my TableView unreachable. My whole Table View storyboard is instantiated from a nib, and when I try to navigate to the Table View, it now skips to the Details View. And I can't reach the TableView by clicking 'Done' on the Details View anymore. Can you advise further?

Comment: Let's name the table views first so that it is easier to address different table views. Let's call them NHCMaster and MHCDetail. On your storyboard you should only have 3 things. 1 Navigator Controller as the initial view. This navigator controller is connected to NHCMaster. Then NHCMaster should be connected to NHCDetail.

Comment: 'Done' on the MHCDetail should trigger [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in MHCDetail in order to remove NHCDetail thus NHCMaster can be viewed again.

Comment: Wow, changing this is going to break a lot of my code. Note to others: do not use this tutorial to build tables unless you are experienced with tables AND storyboards: [http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1).

Comment: It seems that you have many more view controllers on your storyboard. Just make sure that when you "navigate to the Table View", you actually access/refer the Navigation Controller of the Table View instead of the Tabel View directly.

Comment: Thank you so kindly for your very helpful pointers. I am on my way to sorting out this mess!

Comment: I have one additional question. My previous method of reloading the table cell data no longer works. Where should I now place the code the reload the table cell data?

Comment: Should be in NHCMaster in viewWillAppear